# Why views.py and not controller.py

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

In most MVC/ORM type systems django's views.py might be referred to as a controller, and their templates the views. Is this a different design pattern that they are following? Why is it called views.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is answered in the [FAQ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names).

> **Django appears to be a MVC framework, but you call the Controller the
>   “view”, and the View the “template”. How come you don’t use the
>   standard names?**
>
> Well, the standard names are debatable.
>
> In our interpretation of MVC, the “view” describes the data that gets
>   presented to the user. It’s not necessarily how the data looks, but
>   which data is presented. The view describes which data you see, not
>   how you see it. It’s a subtle distinction.
>
> So, in our case, a “view” is the Python callback function for a
>   particular URL, because that callback function describes which data is
>   presented.
>
> Furthermore, it’s sensible to separate content from presentation –
>   which is where templates come in. In Django, a “view” describes which
>   data is presented, but a view normally delegates to a template, which
>   describes how the data is presented.
>
> Where does the “controller” fit in, then? In Django’s case, it’s
>   probably the framework itself: the machinery that sends a request to
>   the appropriate view, according to the Django URL configuration.
>
> If you’re hungry for acronyms, you might say that Django is a “MTV”
>   framework – that is, “model”, “template”, and “view.” That breakdown
>   makes much more sense.
>
> At the end of the day, of course, it comes down to getting stuff done.
>   And, regardless of how things are named, Django gets stuff done in a
>   way that’s most logical to us.